# How to call stored procedure on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Error comes when i run update stored procedure in laravel5 like this..

> QueryException in `Connection.php line 620:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]:` Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'Sandeep,09999999999,,,sandeep@gmail.com,,,,,,,)'` at line 1 `(SQL: call sp_clientupdate(108, Sandeep,09999999999,,,sandeep@gmail.com,,,,,,,))`

my code is....

```
return DB::select('call sp_clientupdate(108, Sandeep,0999999999,,,sandeep@gmail.com,,,,,,,)');
```

Pls anyone give me solution.....

Comment: show your query with question

Comment: Use `DB::statement` instead.

Comment: please, read something about SQL injections.

Comment: According to https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database, DB::statement returns null; hence, it would appear that you must use DB::select if you expect a result set. That said, I agree that you should frown upon using raw SQL. Given that the OP is calling a stored procedure, it seems to me that he feels the same way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You change.

```
return DB::select('call sp_clientupdate("108", "Sandeep","0999999999","","","sandeep@gmail.com","","","","","","",)');
```

Try it's working perfectly....

Comment: My take-away from this exchange is that the OP failed to take into account that MySQL stored routines don't support optional parameters. Perhaps, like me, he is coming from something along the lines of Microsoft SQL Server, which does.

Answer (score 15):

Try this one,

```
DB::statement('call sp_clientupdate("108", "Sandeep","0999999999","","","sandeep@gmail.com","","","","","","",)');
```

It works perfectly.

Comment: how to fire an event after procedure. I am getting this error Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 36. Packet size=10