# How to execute Stored Procedure from Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I need to execute a stored procedure after my form submits data. I have the stored procedure working like I want it, and I have my form working properly. I just do not know the statement to execute the sp from laravel 5.

it should be something like this: execute my_stored_procedure. but I can not seem to find anything like that online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call stored procedure on Laravel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498227/how-to-call-stored-procedure-on-laravel)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try something like this

```
DB::select('exec my_stored_procedure("Param1", "param2",..)');
```

or

```
DB::select('exec my_stored_procedure(?,?,..)',array($Param1,$param2));
```

Try this for without parameters

```
DB::select('EXEC my_stored_procedure')
```

Comment: I do not need to return anything, and my stored procedure does not need any parameters. so could I do DB::select('my_stored_procedure')   ?

Comment: @JordanDavis - check now

Comment: Thanks, it now tries to run the SP, however it looks like my server does not have the needed permissions to do so

Comment: Its your `login` which don't have permission to `execute` any thing in `Server`. Contact your DBA

Comment: @JordanDavis If you don't need anything returned from the stored procedure, you can also use DB::statement instead of DB::select

Comment: my error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXEC rule_4' at line 1 (SQL: EXEC rule_4)`

Comment: @Pரதீப் Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838922/how-can-i-convert-many-statement-mysql-to-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 21):

You can also do this:

```
DB::select("CALL my_stored_procedure()");
```

Answer (score 8):

for **Laravel 5.4**

---

```
DB::select(DB::raw("exec my_stored_procedure"));
```

---

if you want to pass parameters:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("exec my_stored_procedure :Param1, :Param2"),[
    ':Param1' => $param_1,
    ':Param2' => $param_2,
]);
```

Answer (score 7):

for Laravel 5.5

```
DB::select('call myStoredProcedure("p1", "p2")');
```

or

```
DB::select('call myStoredProcedure(?,?)',array($p1,$p2));
```

no parameter

```
DB::select('call myStoredProcedure()')
```

Answer (score 4):

Running the Microsoft SQL Server Stored Procedure (MS SQL Server) using PHP Laravel framework.
If you are trying to run SP using Laravel Model then you can use following two approaches.

```
$submit = DB::select(" EXEC ReturnIdExample ?,?", array( $paramOne ,$paramTwo ) ); 

$submit = DB::select(" EXEC ReturnIdExample $paramOne,$paramTwo ");
```

If incase you are passing the Varchar Parameter then use the following:

```
$submit = DB::select(" EXEC ReturnIdExample '$paramOne', '$paramTwo' ");
```

If you are just passing parameter which are of INT or BIGINT then this should work and you can get the return from SP:

```
$submit = DB::select(" EXEC ReturnIdExample $paramOne,$paramTwo ");
```

Once the stored procedure is executed the values will be present in the `$submit` in the form of array, you need to loop through it and access the required columns.

```
foreach($submit  as $row)
{

echo $row->COLUMN1;
echo $row->COLUMN2;
echo $row->COLUMN3;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For version 5.5 use `CALL`:

```
return DB::select(DB::raw('call store_procedure_function(?)', [$parameter]))
```

Answer (score 2):

After a long research, this works:

```
DB::connection("sqlsrv")->statement('exec Pro_Internal_Transfer_Note_post @mvoucherid='.$VMID);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app('db')->getPdo()->exec('exec my_stored_procedure');
```

Comment: Is this laravel answer?

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: @MunimMunna of course it is, app() is a Laravel Helper.

Answer (score 1):

Working code with Laraval 5.6,

```
DB::select('EXEC my_stored_procedure ?,?,?',['var1','var2','var3']);
```

Answer (score 1):

MySql with Laravel `5.6`(or above version may be)

```
DB::select(
    'call sp($id)'
);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Comment: @byaruhaf Thanks for your suggestion. I've added the scenario to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If your stored procedure always returns something then you can go with

```
DB::select("exec StoredProcedure '1','A','PARAM');
```

Otherwise (if there is no response from the SP) it will throw an exception. In that case I recommend using

```
DB::statetment("exec StoredProcedure '1','A','PARAM'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Real world from my Aplicaction Example Use

$result = DB::connection("sqlsrv")->statement("exec p_SaveOrderWithRelation  @cOrderID='{$order->id}', @cPaymentID='{$payment->id}', @cShiftID='{$shift->id}', @cSimple=0");
return $result;

# My PrimaryKey in Models is string type like, and i must put parametr ID like string type:

namespace App\Traits;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait Uuids
{
    /**
     * Boot function from Laravel.
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            if (empty($model->{$model->getKeyName()})) {
                $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::upper(Uuid::uuid4()->toString()); 
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Get the value indicating whether the IDs are incrementing.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIncrementing()
    {
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Get the auto-incrementing key type.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKeyType()
    {
        return 'string';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple statements fetch from procedure, follow the following code:

```
$conn = DB::connection('sqlsrv');
    $sql = "exec [sp_name]";

    $pdo = $conn->getPdo()->prepare($sql);
    $pdo->execute();

    $res = array();
    do {
        array_push($res, $pdo->fetchAll());
       } while ($pdo->nextRowset());

    echo "<pre />";
    print_r($res);
    exit();
```