# Where and how to create a stored procedure in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

I am using laravel 5.1 for my project and till now it us going perfect until I wanted to use stored procedure in it.

so far I have gathered the information as

```
 $result = DB::select('call InsertNewApplicant(?????????????????????????)',
                    array($firstName, $middleName, $addressLine_1, $addressLine_2, $postCode, $landline, $mobile, $email,
                    $DOB, $maritalStatus, $industry, $occupation, $jobTitle, $selfEmployed, $selfAssessment, $workHome,
                    $ownTransport, $companyVehicle, $paySubs, $otherIncome, $printForms, $marketingUs, $marketingOther,
                    $agreedTNCs, $TNCVersion, $CampaignSource));
```

might be using this code for the controller to update any data from mysql,
but as a beginner in Laravel, I have no idea where to define my stored procedure and in which file

I have visited many links , but all I could get is this code, not a single perfect example.

Can you please elaborate a small example on how to call a stored procedure in controller for a specific action?

and what all are prerequisite and other things that has to be taken care of

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34497114 ?

Comment: so u mean to say is, all i have to do is when I submit any form I just paste this code in my controller and thats it?

Comment: My friend I have no idea. I just saw the lack of commas between your question marks and did a google. I do mysql and php but not laravel

Comment: ohh ok ..thank you for the efforts though

Answer (score 0):

**Wow wow wow**. You are using Laravel, so please don't write code like that. It's a sin!

Please read up on the following examples from the Laravel quickstart guide:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart#eloquent-models
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart#creating-the-task

The first one is regarding Eloquent models (which you should **definitely** use) and the second one shows you how to store data in your database using these models.

---

Now on to the task at hand. I think that using

```
DB::statement(DB::raw("CALL InsertNewApplicant('$firstName', '$middleName');"));
```

and so on, so forth should do the trick...

Comment: With this example you are creating SQL injection vulnerability .

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Put it into a controller, and keep it this way until you would like to change something. Than you can abstract it out to dedicated class that may be mocked.