# Can I use eloquent connection and start the procedure?

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to get the data on database using stored procedure - can I use the eloquent?

This is my Eloquent

**TriedHard.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TriedHard extends Model
{
    //
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv2';
}
```

and I try to call this eloquent on my query like this so I can use a stored procedure.

**Controller.php**:

```
$dataprogram =  TriedHard::select('sp_MstShow_CrewProgram_Select');
dump(collect($dataprogram);
```

but nothing happened, also I can't get my data, how can I solve that?

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354611/how-to-call-stored-procedure-with-eloquent-laravel)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call Stored Procedure with Eloquent (Laravel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354611/how-to-call-stored-procedure-with-eloquent-laravel)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any use of calling a stored procedure with Eloquent.
Rather just use `DB` connection to connect specific 'DB' like below:-

```
$db = DB::connection($DBconnectionName)
```

and use

```
 $db = DB::connection($DBconnectionName)->select('sp_MstShow_CrewProgram_Select')
```