# How can I include a procedure in my Eloquent ORM laravel select?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, procedure

How can I include a procedure in my Eloquent ORM select laravel?

I would like to call my procedure `call pro_get_products_in_stock(0)` function inside my select, as in the block below:

```
 $list = Product::query()->select(DB::raw('call pro_get_products_in_stock(0)'))->get();
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Eloquent for this operation.

What you can use is the Query builder.

```
$query = DB::select('call pro_get_products_in_stock(?)', [0]);
$result = collect($query);
```

---

Note, I have not tested it yet, this answer is based on an article of Medium and a SO answer.

https://medium.com/@smayzes/stored-procedures-in-laravel-60e7cb255fc9

[How to call Stored Procedure with Eloquent (Laravel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354611/how-to-call-stored-procedure-with-eloquent-laravel)

Comment: OK thank you. I thought it was possible. I had to do without the procedure.