# Can I build web API in Laravel with existing stored procedures in database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I am very new to Laravel and web API and I could not find any answers that is talking about building web API in Laravel using existing stored procedures or stored functions in mysql.

So my question is:
Can I build web API using my existing stored procedures or functions? if it is possible please give me some guidelines.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to execute Stored Procedure from Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497063/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-from-laravel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute Stored Procedure from Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497063/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-from-laravel)