# Executing stored procedure in php laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I am using Laravel 7 and I want to show the results from the stored procedure. My code is given below. When I execute the stored procedure with parameters in SQL Server, it's showing data. But in Laravel application data is not showing.

Please, help me to find the problem.

```
$serverName = env("DB_HOST");
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>env("DB_DATABASE"), "UID"=>env("DB_USERNAME"), "PWD"=>env("DB_PASSWORD") );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$tsql= " EXEC USP_Daily_TA_Punching_Detailswith_OT '$employee','$datefrom','$dateto'";
$getResults= sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
      $data = array();
      if ($getResults == FALSE)
      {
      echo '';
      }
      else {
       //$data[] ='';
      do
      {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
         $data[] = $row;
        }
      }
       while (sqlsrv_next_result($getResults));
      }
      if(count($data)>0){
       sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
      $total_row = count($data);
     }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute Stored Procedure from Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497063/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-from-laravel)

Comment: Well, this is not exactly `Laravel` code, because you are using _sqlsrv__ functions from PHP Driver for SQL Server. Do you want to fix this code without using a Laravel approach?

Comment: i tried with laravel, but its showing error "SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '000010993'. (SQL: exec USP_Daily_TA_Punching_Detailswith_OT('000010993','2020-06-01','2020-06-10'))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to use parameters in your statements to prevent possible SQL injection issues. As an additional note, use unambiguous date format, when you pass date values to SQL Server:

Example using PHP Driver for SQL Server:

```
<?php
// Connection
$serverName = env("DB_HOST");
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database"=>env("DB_DATABASE"), 
    "UID"=>env("DB_USERNAME"), 
    "PWD"=>env("DB_PASSWORD")
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Statement
$employee = '000010993';
$datefrom = '20200601'; 
$dateto   = '20200610';
$tsql     = "EXEC USP_Daily_TA_Punching_Detailswith_OT ?, ?, ?";
$params   = array($employee, $datefrom, $dateto);
$getResults = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);
if ($getResults === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}   

// Results
$data = array();
do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($getResults));

// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
$total_row = count($data);
?>
```

Example using Laravel:

```
<?php

...
$employee = '000010993';
$datefrom = '20200601'; 
$dateto   = '20200610';
DB::select("SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC USP_Daily_TA_Punching_Detailswith_OT ?, ?, ?", array($employee, $datefrom, $dateto));

...
?>
```

Comment: Using PHP, when i print $data, there is no data..showing []



Using laravel, its showing "SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields. (SQL: EXEC USP_Daily_TA_Punching_Detailswith_OT 000010993, 2020-06-01, 2020-06-10)"

Comment: @ManUtd Can you change the stored procedure and place `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in the procedure?

Comment: @ManUtd Or execurte `sqlsrv_next_result($getResults)` to skip possible information messages: `sqlsrv_next_result($getResults); while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {$data[] = $row;}`.

Comment: i think problem with stored procedure, when i change to some test stored procedure, its working, but this stored procedure not showing data. how can i see the errors in stored procedure in php. when i execute stored procedure in sql server i am getting data, but here in my application no data.

Comment: when i print print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true), its showing Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01000
            [SQLSTATE] => 01000
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]2020-06-01
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]2020-06-01
        )

)

whats that means?

Comment: @ManUtd How do you pass date values. Use unambiguous date format ('20200601').

Comment: By using laravel, i include SET NOCOUNT ON at beginning. DB::select("SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC ......"). Now its working!.. Thanku @Zhorov

Answer (score 0):

Try the below to call the store procedure in laravel

```
DB::select("call USP_Daily_TA_Punching_Detailswith_OT('".$employee."','".$datefrom."','".$dateto."')");
```

Comment: its showing "SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '000010993'. (SQL: call USP_Daily_TA_Punching_Detailswith_OT('000010993','2020-06-01','2020-06-10'))"

Comment: can you try without quotes for first parameter as it is showing error here.

Comment: same error "SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '000010993'. (SQL: call USP_Daily_TA_Punching_Detailswith_OT(000010993,'2020-06-01','2020-06-10'))"