# Laravel SQL Server Stored Procedure doesn't return correct values

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-query-builder

Laravel version:7.6,
SQL Server version: 2019,

I was going to get stored procedure as following:

```
$result = \DB::select(\DB::raw("exec myStoredProcedure:type"),[
     ':type' => "A",
]);
dd($result); // return value is only text
```

`$result` returned only one text.

Actually `$result` should have returned array. `array[0]` is one text sentence, `array[1]` is table array.

When I run this in SSMS, it returned exactly what I wanted. array[0] and array[1].

Could you please help me?

---

I also tried like this to solve this issue.

```
$result = \DB::select('exec myStoredProcedure(?)', ["A"]); // error 

$result = \DB::select('exec myStoredProcedure("A")); // error
```

Above two results showed error.

I tried with core php as following:

```
 $serverName = "localhost";
  $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"myDB", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"myPsw");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
  $query = "SET NOCOUNT ON; exec myStoredProcedure@type= A";

  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

  $next_result = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);

  $array = [];

  if( $next_result ) {
     while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $array[]=$row;
     }
  } elseif( is_null($next_result)) {
       echo "No more results.<br />";
  } else {
       die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
dd($array); // this returned only array[1] which is table array.
```

Comment: A similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62297185/executing-stored-procedure-in-php-laravel/62297711#62297711), which is a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: Great Thanks, in your answer, php executing result was what I wanted exactly. But second paragraph:(laravel answer) returned only text which is array[0]. Could you please let me know laravel result? Thanks