# How to execute MySQL Stored Procedure from Laravel 8.0^ with ANY parameters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

I have recently gone over SQL Stored Procedures using Laravel. I had a lot of issues and troubles trying to call my procedure with both input and output data. I use Laravel 8.0^.

Now, I went over this old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497063/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-from-laravel) that helped a little but is now obsolete, and I would like to get the best possible way to call a procedure with input and output parameters

Answer (score 3):

Laravel itself does not support any method Procedures call (like it does with DB::select() for SELECT queries), so you will have to write a Raw SQL call.

Now, there are 4 cases for procedures, and they depend on whether you are inserting or getting data from the procedure itself, or not getting anything at all. I will go over all of them:

**parameterless procedure call**

This type of call is a simple procedure executed from Laravel that needs no input data nor returns any. It can be done in such way:

```
$query = "CALL your_stored_procedure(); COMMIT;";

DB::statement($query);
```

**procedure call with ONLY input parameters**

This type of call is a simple procedure that is similar to what you have seen above, but we pass data in it. It can be done in 2 ways, depending on your needings:

```
//passing static data in the procedure
//your_data can be a String, int float, and so on depending on the type in the procedure
$query = "CALL your_stored_procedure(your_data); COMMIT;";

DB::statement($query);
```

```
//passing dynamic data in the procedure
$query = "CALL your_stored_procedure(:your_data); COMMIT;";

$bind = [
    'your_data' => $your_data
]

DB::statement($query, $bind);
```

**procedure call with ONLY output parameters**

This type of call is a simple procedure that is similar to what you have seen above, but we get data from it. It can be done this very simple way:

```
//getting data from the procedure
$query = "CALL your_stored_procedure(@your_output_data); COMMIT;";

//calling the procedure
DB::statement($query);

//getting the data from the variable in the procedure
$return_query = "SELECT @your_output_data AS your_output_data";

$result = DB::select($return_query);
DB::statement($return_query);

//doing what you want with the data you get
var_dump($result);
```

**procedure call with BOTH input and output parameters**

Like the above procedures, this is a mixture of them all and is aimed at showing how to call a procedure with data in it and getting data back from it:

```
//passing dynamic data in the procedure
$query = "CALL your_stored_procedure(:your_input_data, @your_output_data); COMMIT;";

$bind = [
    'your_input_data' => $your_input_data
]

DB::statement($query, $bind);

//getting the data from the variable in the procedure
$return_query = "SELECT @your_output_data AS your_output_data";

$result = DB::select($return_query);
DB::statement($return_query);

//doing what you want with the data you get
var_dump($result);
```

Why am I using `COMMIT`? COMMIT is used by the DBMS to make a permanent edit on the updated table where the procedure has been called. Almost every DBMS nowadays has a thing called `AUTOCOMMIT` that does this for us. However, this will not let us call a possible `ROLLBACK` in case we'd need to restore or cancel the changes made, and that's why I used COMMIT at the end of every procedure call

you are free to comment asking anything you need

N.B.

Mind the answer is aimed at showing HOW to make a procedure call on Laravel, not on how to handle the response from it (if there was any)

Comment: @noxtor can you help me I have tried as you mention above procedure call with BOTH input and output parameters...but did not have any success.
to see my problem in detail please visit the below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73387454/getting-output-parameter-value-from-microsoft-sql-stored-procedure-using-laravel