# Getting output parameter value from Microsoft SQL stored procedure using Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I am trying to insert a record into the Microsoft SQL database via store procedure using Laravel and get the value from an output parameter. My record is inserted but did not get `@RetValue`.
For this, I tried

```
DB::select("DECLARE @RetValue INT; SELECT @RetValue as 'return'; EXEC AddDistrict 'somevalue', 1, @RetValue OUTPUT; SELECT @RetValue as 'abc';");
DB::select(DB::Raw("Declare @RetValue int EXEC AddDistrict 'somevalue', '1', @RetValue OUTPUT"),'select @RetValue as abc');
DB::select(DB::statement('CALL AddDistrict("DName"="asdfasdf", "PID"=1,"RetValue"="" )').'@RetValue as RetValue');
DB::select(" EXEC AddDistrict ?, ?", array( 'some_value',1));
DB::select(DB::raw("exec AddDistrict @DName = 'some_value', @PID = 1, @RetValue=''"));
DB::select('CALL AddDistrict(?, ?, ?)',
     array(
        'DName' => $request->DistrictName,
        'PID' => $request->province,
         'RetValue' => ''
        ));
DB::select('exec AddDistrict(?,?)',"some_value',1);
```

and many others but did not get the @RetValue. mostly I get an empty array like this [].

My Store Procedure looks like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddDistrict]
    
    @DName nvarchar(50)
    ,@PID int
    
    ,@RetValue int output
    
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if not exists(select * from District where District_Name = @DName)

begin
    INSERT INTO [dbo].District
           ([District_Name],ProvienceID)
     VALUES (@DName,@PID)
     set @RetValue=1;
     end
     else
     begin
     set @RetValue=-1;
     end
END
```

I want if the record inserts then give me 1 if did not insert then give me -1 as described in the SP

Comment: @Larnu Yes, of course, I am talking about the output parameter. sorry for not conveying my message properly.

Comment: yes, I wanted OUTPUT parameters.

Comment: can you help me I search alot.

Comment: Remove all CALL statements, those are not the syntax of SQL Server. I then used DB::statement to launch a procedure. Mine was on MySQL and not on SQLS. You may want to see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16) for this

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to that. Maybe it's not the proper way. But my code is now running smoothly after the below changes.
Just remove this variable `@RetValue int output` and replace `set @RetValue=1;` to `SELECT 1;`